# Seaborn JointGrid hexplot: aspect ratio issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to create a JointGrid plot but I'm having some trouble with getting the aspect ratio right. The relevant code and the figure are attached below. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
fig = plt.figure()
sns.set_style("ticks")
g = sns.JointGrid(X, Y, xlim=[0, max(X)], ylim=[0, max(Y)])
g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, color=".5")
g.plot_joint(plt.hexbin, bins='log', gridsize=30, cmap=color)
```

And the output figure:
[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; I looked at this: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/271 but the fix there didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you put the colorbar there?

Comment: You can add code like this: cax = g.fig.add_axes([1, 0.20, .01, 0.5]); cb = plt.colorbar(cax=cax)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out; posting my solution here just in case anyone has the same issue in the future.

```
fig = plt.figure()
sns.set_style("ticks")
g = sns.JointGrid(X, Y)
g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, color=".5")
g.plot_joint(plt.hexbin, bins='log', gridsize=30, cmap=color, extent=[0, np.max(X), 0, np.max(X)])
```

I essentially just set the extents for both of them to be equal to the maximum value of the X array (which has a higher maxima than Y, causing the weird aspect ratio).

The end result is this:

[image]